# How can you diagnose the cause of slowness for some users but not all?

Tags: asp.net, iis, isp

We are getting reports from a handful of users that our web application is loading very slowly for them.  So slowly that many of their page requests are timing out.

The majority of our users are not experiencing this.

The users who are getting the slowness don't have problems accessing any other site.

We can log in to their instance of the application and from our connection everything is fast.

We have set up screen-sharing with the affected users and have seen first-hand the slowness they are experiencing.

These customers are getting very upset and blaming us, even though we believe the fault lies somewhere else.  We're about to lose customers.

tracert doesn't return anything.  every request times out.

I'm really out of my realm of expertise here and I have no idea where to begin hunting this issue down, any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: With Chrome, for example, the developer tools can provide waterfall style analysis and can pinpoint timing issues. I am sure some of the other browsers offer the same option. I am not sure about IE which I assume most people are using. Are there any users out there with a browser that can provide this analysis?

Comment: Yes, we could get some users to do this.  However, I'm not sure what it would tell us.  Looking at the "Network" tab in chrome devtools shows me each resource that is being loaded and the time it takes, but all of the resources are coming from the same place.

Comment: It would help you narrow down which resource is causing the slowness (if it's just one), whether it's DNS/network related. Definitely worth a go.

Comment: You are right, except that sometimes certain resources load differently. It may not tell you anything useful, but that would be the first step I would take. The next thing I would do is use something like WireShark to see where the bottle-neck is. But that may be too tall a task for a user. Are any of them close by? You could visit and use your own computer to figure things out.

Comment: @Tim Fountain is right. The Chrome devtool can at least tell you if there is anything obvious. WireShark can tell you if there is anything not-so-obvious. For example, I found that my new firewall was fragmenting DNS calls which caused them to fail on a periodic and regular basis. I was able to solve the problem by analyzing the traffic.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions, I will try them.  We are able to do screen-sharing with some users and can use wire-shark ourselves.

Comment: Can you let us know what was the real trouble once you find out? Don't misunderstand, but I am asking out of mere curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These issues are often hard to trace back to it's origin. Here are a few things you can do to try and figure out where the problem is exactly.

One simple trick is to create a fairly sizable but not huge HTML file and put it in the web space. You can optionally include a couple of sizable but not huge images in the HTML file. You can ask if your users (that are having trouble) to access this page several times over a period to make sure that the page loads as it should. This will tell you a few things; that the issue is not a network issue, it is not a browser issue (generally), and that it is not a web server issue.

If this works okay, then another thing you can do is to change your application/page to load the JavaScript last as a test to see if there is a JavaScript load and execution issue that is stopping the page from loading. Not all code errors result in an exception of some sort. It is possible that there is a JavaScript incompatibility that exists in some browsers by brand and version. Not all browsers execute JavaScript the same so code can execute fine some or most places and not others. Loading the JavaScript last will allow the page to load while the error remains. This will indicate a possible JavaScript problem.

If these simple tests go well, then I would be looking at two other things.

It may not tell you much, but I would use Chrome or some other browser that provides a waterfall style analysis of load times. You may have to migrate around the application/site or refresh pages until the problem reappears. Chrome has a developers tool that will allow you to see if there is a particular issue with downloading/rendering any portion of your page/site. It will not tell you if you have any latency in queries or anything else that renders the page, but it will indicate that the page is slow to render. It will also tell you if images, JavaScript, or other resource is not loading quickly as it should.

If your page renders slowly, then you will want to look at what causes this. If, for example, a database query is occasionally slow, you can look to your database server for answers. Not knowing SQL Server anymore, I can tell you that MySQL has a slow query log that can be enabled. Some installs have this feature enabled during install. It does require a restart of the server to enable this feature, but is a good idea to do from time to time to tune slower queries (anyhow) so it is something to consider when changes are made.

Lastly, there is always a network issue that may exist. It can be obscure. I use WireShark when I have issues to analyze. This is too huge and technical to discuss, but once the problem occurs, you should be able to parse the network traffic to determine if there are any errors along the way. For example, I used WireShark to determine that my new firewall was fragmenting DNS queries that would occasionally fail causing problems and being quite frustrating. I was able to view the DNS query traffic to determine that an *authority required* bit was set (which is not normally bad) and the query was fragmented not allowing an authority look-up to succeed without specifying a trace. Without the authority required bit set, the DNS query would return a non-authoritative response if possible even if the request was fragmented. But DNS queries for authoritative responses require that the DNS query not be fragmented. Hence the problem. You may have an issue that is that obscure. It may be difficult to find. Let's hope not!

It can be very frustrating to have a customer experience these issues. I know! It is like having egg on your face, but as we in the IT world know all too well, these things happen from time to time. The key is to analyze the issue to know where to look and resolve the problem quickly. Duh! But it is also important that your customer see you go to extraordinary lengths to solve the problem and exactly how technical and obscure it can be. They may not understand it, but they will appreciate the sweat equity in solving the problem and your clear expertise in tracking the problem down. Heck! They may bake you a cake or buy you a beer! Now wouldn't that be nice? As the great and illustrious Homer said (Simpson that is), "Hummmmm cake." In fact, I think he also said "Hummmmm beer."

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  Sorry I'm a little slow in responding.  I'm trying to work my way through some of these suggestions on top of my regular work load.  I'm a developer not a network admin, so a lot of this stuff is kind of new to me.  Wireshark definitely has a learning curve to it.  You've been very helpful though, so thanks.

Comment: @matthew_360 Anytime! You are right, network communications is rather complicated and can make even seasoned veterans go cross-eyed. But it is always a fantastic way to learn interesting things. As a coder, I am sure you see behaviors in applications that makes problems clearer. You think back to how you would code something and the problem cuts itself in half. I was a DEC hardware and VMS internals guy and VMS is the foundation for Windows NT+. 30 year old experience still comes in handy! The same it true for network stuff which I have also done over 30 years. The more you know the better!

Answer (score 5):

There are two main approaches to figuring this type of thing out. Either determine what is the common factor shared by the affected users, or what changed recently so that these users are suddenly affected. Your best bet is to approach it from both directions, as the answer ends up being a mixture of both.

#### What Ties These Users Together?

If they don't have problems with other sites, that cuts out the user network (but it could still be network related at your site's end).

How is your site load balanced? Are all of the affected users hitting a particularly slow instance or server? (You should have some sort of server performance monitoring tool in place to detect this)

Are these users all using a particular browser or version of a browser? Your site might have a bug when accessed by that version.

Do these users share a common privilege or access level on the site? There may be a bug involved with that privilege.

Are these users in the same geographical area? It might be a local ISP (Although if other sites are fine, chances are the ISP has nothing to do with it)

#### What Changed Recently?

Assuming that these users were able to access the site normally before, something changed to cause this issue.

Has there been any server configuration changes recently?

Have there been any code or database changes recently?

Are there new traffic patterns? (surge or lull in traffic may affect how your site is being cached)

#### Dealing with tracert (all credit to closetnoc for correcting me)

> Tracert uses ping to ping each router of a proposed route and ping can be disabled at any router along the way, so to say that a tracert that fails means... anything at all... is incorrect. It just means that a ping response to any point of a proposed route fails. Nothing more. Keep in mind, that often tracert is a proposed route which does NOT always end up being the actual route. It is an important tool, but not always an indicator of a problem. Ping requests can be dropped by rule when traffic passes normally.

#### tl;dr

I realize that answering a question with many more questions is not that great of a practice. The idea here is that you need to ask yourself these types of questions until you figure out what ties the users together (and then something related to that commonality is why they are all affected), or what changed recently (and then something related to the change us what broke), or a combination of the two (e.g., we recently launched a new feature that causes the site to hang in IE 6, so only the IE 6 users are affected and it started happening because of the new feature.)

Comment: I was reading your answer and stopped at the tracert bit. Tracert uses ping to ping each router of a proposed route and ping can be disabled at any router along the way, so to say that a tracert that fails means... anything at all... is incorrect. It just means that a ping response to any point of a proposed route fails. Nothing more. Keep in mind, that often tracert is a proposed route which does NOT always end up being the actual route. It is an important tool, but not always an indicator of a problem. Ping requests can be dropped by rule when traffic passes normally.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to write all this out. You've given me a lot to go on.  Our support staff has been asking these users these questions about location, ISP, browser, etc... but so far we haven't determined any common factor.

Comment: @closetnoc I assumed that was the case, and that ping requests were disabled.  I was incorrect when I said they "all timed out" the very first one to the default gateway does show up, but that's not really very useful.

Comment: "Are all of the affected users hitting a particularly slow instance or server? "  The thing is that I can access the same exact instance on which they are experiencing the slowness, and it is normal speed for me.

Comment: A waterfall report may tell you if any element is not downloading as you think. WireShark can tell you if there is a communication issue. But I forgot about other elements such as JavaScript code errors that do no trigger an exception. It maybe that the site is loading, but while JavaScript is loading and doing what it thinks is right, and but because JavaScript is interpreted differently per browser/brand/version may not be completing and thus stopping the remainder of the page download. You can test this by making sure the JavaScript loads last.

Comment: Another odd trick that I have used is to create a moderately large HTML file that I ask people to access. I keep it in the web space and outside of applications as not to pollute the results. I might put an image or two, not big but not small either- but a good size. If they can download the page consistently, then it is not the network, web server, or browser (except possible JavaScript interpreters). It is something else. Just 5 cents worth of simple deduction.

Comment: @closetnoc - Your explanation of the tracert results is much better  than mine, so I incorporated your comment into the main answer.

Comment: @closetnoc Using a separate HTML file to download outside of the app is a very useful tactic. Same goes for the javascript checking. I think you have enough in the comments to put together an answer yourself that i'd be happy to vote up.

Comment: Done and done! What ever that means...? I hope you find the answer. I am around and if I think of anything else to add, I will chime in.

Answer (score 4):

Are all requests from those users slow or only some of them? Does it happen to them on all browsers? Can you write a test program, that does the same queries without a browser? Is anti-virus enabled? Firefox has safebrowsing, which first queries google if the pages you want to visit are safe.

Best thing you can get is a full trace with wireshark, so you can analyze it and see if it is a DNS problem, dropped packets or whatever. Installation is not that bad either, if you have a remote session open to them, you can do all except entering the admin password.

Are you using SSL (https) requests? It might be that their browser is using a different method for cryptography.

It can be any part of hardware involved, is it possible to use another computer in their network? Or maybe take one of their computers/laptops to a network where everything works? Maybe a mobile phone with Wifi?

If not, can you create them a linux live CD and let them run Firefox there?

There is tons of stuff to test before giving up, just make sure the users understand that and see you are doing everything possible to help them. Often we only see the technical side, but this is a lot about trust too.

You could hire a PC support company located close to them and let them help you analyze the problem there with extra hardware.

Of course it would help if you can post more details about your server and maybe a link with a demo account so people can take a look and you get some more ideas.

Oh, there was also something with IPv6, that it first tried to resolve an AAAA address before using IPv4 A addresses. Don't remember who did that, but you can see those queries in a wireshark capture. Also Windows Name Resolution with Discovery Mode was a problem once.